# how to write client side events functions for the combobox items

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBox2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            SelectedIndex="-1" onselectedindexchanged="ASPxComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged1" > 
        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) {
    grid.SelectRows();}" />            
                                 <Items>                                    
                                 <dx:ListEditItem Text="Selecte All Rows" /> 
                                 <dx:ListEditItem Text="UnselectAll" />                              
                                 </Items>
              </dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

I want to write event for the "unselect all" item in combobox. How can I do this?

Comment: use jquery/javascript for client-side things

Comment: Not sure to understand, you are speaking about Drop Down List? and you want some code run on the client side when all the items are unselected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a JavaScript function that iterates thru the combo-box 
and marks all selected items as false.

See [Select/unselect all checkbox fields using pure Javascript and HTML](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=29609) for sample code

[MSDN: Working with Client-Side Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').each( function() {
     this.checked = false;
});
```